# Counter Refresh, slowing down grid validation

Tags: c#

I have a DataGridView with up to 56000 row pairs with up to 20 columns being evaluated. I have to loop through the DGV and then each cell to verify it it matches, if not then back color is set to red. i display a panel with a counter i of x records being processed where the I is the current value of my iteration. To get the new i value to show i have to do a applicaiton.doevent(). This SLOWS everything down. for example 1000 rows with 10 columns takes about 5-7 seconds with out the counter up counting but almost 45 seconds with the counter running. Is there a faster way to handle a counter?

As stated with a counter 5-10 times slower with out counter very quick

```cs
    private void newErrorValidation(List<string> lstColName, DataTable _dtErrors)
        {
            int intDtRow = -1;
            string strDtErrorColval = null;



            foreach (DataRow drError in _dtErrors.Rows)
            {
                intDtRow = Convert.ToInt16(drError["row"]);// this is the row being checked from the errortable not the dgvrowid 


                for (int i = 0; i < dgvMatchErrors.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    if (dgvMatchErrors.Rows[i].Cells["row"].Value.ToString() == Convert.ToString(intDtRow))
                    {

                        for (int l = 3; l < lstColName.Count; l++)

                        {

                            if (drError[lstColName[l].ToString()].ToString() == "False")
                            {
                                dgvMatchErrors.Rows[i].Cells[lstColName[l].ToString()].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                            }
                        }
                        updateStatuslbl(i, dgvMatchErrors.RowCount);
                        Application.doevent();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I would love to show the user where the code is at in the processing.

Comment: Tks i can never get the formatting correct when pasting code.